# Existence of solution of coupled PDE system

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

I was trying to show that a coupled system of PDEs has a solution in two different ways. One of them works, but for the other way, I am not able to conclude. Therefore, I would like to know where my mistke is or how I can continue.

The system I am considering is for a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}$ and a smooth vector-valued and time-dependent function $\vec{V}:I\times \mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and has the form

$$\begin{cases}\vec{\nabla}f=-\partial_{t}\vec{V}\\\Delta\vec{V}=\vec{S}\end{cases}$$

where the (smooth) source is a vector-valued function  such that $\partial_{t}^{2}\vec{S}=0$ and such that $\partial_{t}\vec{S}=\vec{\nabla}g$ for some scalar-valued function $g$, which by $\partial_{t}^{2}\vec{S}=0$ is time-independent, i.e. $g:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}$.

The **first approach**, which works (if I am not doing any error) is the following:

1. Take a solution of the equation $\Delta f=-g$, which under
   appropriate boundary/initial conditions exists. By assumption, $g$
   is time-independent (since $\partial_{t}^{2}S=0$) and hence, we can
   take the solution $f$ to be time-independent (which means the first
   equation is satisfied). Next, we use the first equation and define
   $$\vec{V}(\vec{r},t):=-[\vec{\nabla}f(\vec{r})]\cdot
   t+\vec{C}(\vec{r})$$ for some time-independent function $\vec{C}$ to
   be determined later. Now, we have fixed $f$ and $\vec{V}$ and we
   have to check that the second equation is satisfied. For this, we do
   the following steps:

   $$\Delta f=-g\\\vec{\nabla}\Delta
   f=-\vec{\nabla}g\\-\partial_{t}\Delta\vec{V}=-\partial_{t}\vec{S}\\-\Delta\vec{V}+\Delta\vec{C}=-\vec{S}+\vec{S}\vert_{t=0}$$

   where we integrated in the last step. Hence, we set the constants
   $\vec{C}$ to be solutions of the time-independent Poisson equation
   $$\Delta\vec{C}=\vec{S}\vert_{t=0}$$ which again exists under
   suitable assumptions. This concludes the proof.

For the **second approach**,  I do the following:

2. I start by taking a solution of equation 2, which in general has the
   form

   $$\vec{V}(\vec{r},t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\frac{\vec{S}(\vec{r}^{\prime},t)}{\Vert\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{\prime}\Vert}\mathrm{d}^{3}\vec{r}^{\prime}$$
   Now, the second equation states that
   $\vec{\nabla}f=-\partial_{t}\vec{V}$, or in other words, that the
   vector field $\partial_{t}\vec{V}$ is the gradient of a funcion. By
   Helmholtz decomposition, this can only be the case if
   $\partial_{t}\vec{V}$ is rotation free, which I don't see why it
   should be the case:

   $$\vec{\nabla}\times \partial_{t}\vec{V}(\vec{r},t)=
   \int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\vec{\nabla}\times\frac{\partial_{t}\vec{S}(\vec{r}^{\prime},t)}{\Vert\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{\prime}\Vert}\mathrm{d}^{3}\vec{r}^{\prime}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\vec{\nabla}\times\frac{\vec{\nabla}^{\prime}g(\vec{r}^{\prime})}{\Vert\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{\prime}\Vert}\mathrm{d}^{3}\vec{r}^{\prime}$$

   I don't see how this should vanish and hence how to solve the first
   equation for $f$. Does anyone see how to continue? Maybe it also involves using the freedom of adding to $\vec{V}$ a harmonic vector-valued function?

Comment: $f$ is time dependent but $\partial_t f = 0$?

Comment: Yes, sorry a typo.

Comment: Well, I am not so sure about that. I have something like $\vec{\nabla}\times \frac{\vec{C}}{\Vert\vec{r}\Vert}$ where $\vec{C}$ is something constant. For example, the first entry of the resulting vector gives something like $\partial_{2}\frac{C_{3}}{\Vert\vec{r}\Vert}-\partial_{3}\frac{C_{2}}{\Vert\vec{r}\Vert}$.

Comment: Yeah I was hasty about that. Will try again.

Comment: I mean, in principle, I have the freedom to add to $\vec{V}$ a $\vec{W}\cdot t$ where $\vec{W}$ is time-independent and such that $\Delta\vec{W}=0$. Since I also used a similar freedom in my first approach, maybe it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can assume $g$ is bounded (and I believe we can), we can easily show
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^3}\nabla' \frac{g(\vec{r}')}{||\vec{r}-\vec{r}'||}d^3\vec{r}' = 0.
$$
Then we note that for any function $p$, $\nabla'p(\vec{r}-\vec{r}') = -\nabla p(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')$ by the chain rule. This lets us integrate by parts to convert the $\nabla'$ into a $\nabla$:
\begin{multline}
\partial_t \vec{V} = \int_{\mathbb R^3}\frac{\nabla'g(\vec{r}')}{||\vec{r}-\vec{r}'||} d^3\vec{r}'=\int_{\mathbb R^3}\nabla' \frac{g(\vec{r}')}{||\vec{r}-\vec{r}'||}d^3\vec{r}'-\int_{\mathbb R^3}g(\vec{r}')\nabla'\frac{1}{||\vec{r}-\vec{r}'||}d^3\vec{r}' \\
= \int_{\mathbb R^3}g(\vec{r}')\nabla\frac{1}{||\vec{r}-\vec{r}'||}d^3\vec{r}' = \nabla \int_{\mathbb R^3}\frac{g(\vec{r}')}{||\vec{r}-\vec{r}'||} d^3\vec{r}'.
\end{multline}
So $\partial_t\vec{V}$ is indeed a gradient field.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @B.Hueber Also note that's clearly the solution to $\nabla^2 f = - g$.

Comment: Indeed, that makes the bridge to the first approach!